# opencart метод моделя в контроллер

Tags: opencart, view, controller, model

Задача в том что надо передать значении из шаблона. Сделал свою функцию в контролере который вызывает метод моделя что делает запись к базе и вернет обратно уже из базы (Controller):

```
function translateYandex($text){
    $this->model_query_query->getTranslate($text) 
}
```

Вызов из view:

```
translateYandex('text');
```

получаю ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
```

вопрос как пройти задачу не получая ошибку.

Comment: Вы вызываете функцию, которая не принадлежит какому-либо классу. Тем не менее, пытаетесь обращаться в теле этой функции к некоторому экземпляру класса. Переместите функцию в класс или передавайте в неё ссылку на экземпляр класса.

Comment: Да если переместит функцию в класс то все ok, тогда проблема будет в другом, я уже не могу вызывать `translateYandex('text');` из .tpl в opencart я так понял правила mvс нельзя трогать `model` в `view`

Comment: Да, согласно mvc, за связь `model` и `view` должен отвечать `controller`. Он уже может непосредственно обращаться к модели.

Comment: Важ ничего не мешает аяксом из вьюхи дёргать любой метод любого класса в любом контроллере, правда?

Comment: Надо при генерации страниц все сделать.

Comment: покажите весь тест ошибки и кусок кода, на который она(ошибка) ссылается.